# Toggle bootstrap modal using angular variable

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I wrote a bootstrap3 modal for my project before learning angular which was triggered using a button. Now I want to toggle it using angular variable. Taking reference from [this](https://aashishkoirala.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/angular-bootstrap-modal/) article, i have simplified my code as follows:

My modal html:

```
<div id="registered" tabindex="-1" modal-toggle role="dialog" aria-labelledby="registeredModal" aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    ...
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

`modalToggle` directive:

```
app.directive("modalToggle",function(){
  return function(scope, element, attrs){
    scope.$watch(scope.loaded.showModal, function(value) {
                if (value) element.modal('show');
                else element.modal('hide');
    });
  }
})
```

`scope.loaded.showModal` is set on following controller, which is called after i hit tab on my form input:

```
app.controller('validatectrl',[ '$http', '$scope', '$upload', $location, function($http, $scope, $location){
      unique: function(param){
        $scope.loading={};
        $scope.loaded={};
        $scope.loading[param.field]=true;

        var currentPath=$location.path();
        var webCall = $http({
                   method: 'POST',
                   url: currentPath+'/validation',
                   async : true,
                   headers: {
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                   },
                   timeout:10000,
                   data: param});
        webCall.then(handleSuccess,handleError);
        function handleSuccess(response) {
          ...
          if(response.data.status===1) {
            ...
          }
          else if(response.data.status===0){
            $scope.loaded["showModal"]=true;
            alert("duplicate item");
          }
        }
        function handleError(response){
          $scope.loaded[param.field]={};
          $scope.loading[param.field]=false;
          $scope.loaded[param.field]["error"]=true;
          $scope.loaded[param.field]["Message"]="Cannot fetch data from server";
        };
      }
```

Everything else works except for the modal does not pop up.

Comment: You should probably use https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap or similar, instead of vanilla Bootstrap's jQuery-based JavaScript.

Comment: yeah...bt i had already done the prototype in bootstrap's jquery one... n there was time constraint then... m looking into it nw... thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to change from

```
scope.$watch(scope.loaded.showModal, function(value) {
            if (value) element.modal('show');
            else element.modal('hide');
});
```

to

```
scope.$watch(function(){ return scope.loaded.showModal; }, function(value) {
            if (value) element.modal('show');
            else element.modal('hide');
});
```

Hope this help.

Comment: that worked perfectly. thanks a lot. can you please explain what was the issue?

Comment: I'm really sorry but I'm not good enough to explain this in term of technique. But I've faced the problem like this before then I try to return the value from the function and it's work